# Attribute directive to add behavior to another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating totally decoupled directives by using events in angularjs. And as an example, I am using creating a search directive and implemented it this way.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .directive('search', function () {
    return {
      scope: true,
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function($rootScope) {
          var vm = this;

          vm.onChange = function (searchValue) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('searchbox-valuechanged', {data: searchValue});
          };
      },
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      bindToController: true,
      templateUrl: 'search.html'
    };
  });
```

Whereas the html would look like this:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search"
  ng-model="ctrl.searchValue"
  ng-model-options="{debounce: 100}"
  ng-change="ctrl.onChange({search: ctrl.searchValue})">
```

Now I wanted to create another directive that I could add to another directive or element, that would make it's list items searchable. So I named the directive `searchable`

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ap')
  .directive('searchable', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        by: '@'
      },
      controller: function($rootScope, $scope) {
        var vm = $scope.ctrl;
        var items = vm.items;


        $rootScope.$on('ecal:searchbox-valuechanged', function(e, msg) {
          console.log(vm);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

In my mind I should be able to use the `searchable` directive like so:

```
<list-directive items="ctrl.items" searchable by="tags,title"></list-directive>
```

Whereas the searchable directive should be able to iterate through the items in the parent directive and parse the list and return only the items with property value equal to the `by` list.

**Update**

So the questions are:

1. How do I access those `items` from the parent directive
2. How do I filter the list so that it will update the list directives with the filtered items (items that match the search value)

Thanks!

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Okay, I'll update the question, sorry about that